# How to get an array of attributes when there is whitespace characters between the name and value?

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3

I'm trying to get an array of attributes and I'm splitting on the whitespace character. What I have works fine except when namespaces are involved. Here is my sample code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:node something xmlns:s = "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:b='testnamespace.com' xmlns="noprefix.com"></node>
```

Exmascript:

```
var xmlString:String = 'something xmlns:s = "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:b='testnamespace.com' xmlns="noprefix.com"';
var attributes:Array = xmlString.split(/\s+/g);
```

That results in this array of items:

```
 - something
 - xmlns:s
 - =
 - "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
 - xmlns:b='testnamespace.com'
 - xmlns="noprefix.com"
```

How would I split the attributes up when there are spaces between the name and value?

PS:
I have an XML parser but it throws an error because of mismatched namespaces. So I have to parse the attributes and remove or fix invalid namespaces and then I can pass it the XML string.

PSS:
I only need to work with the first tag to add the namespaces. I'm not doing any other string manipulations.

Comment: Use an XML parser instead. JavaScript regular expressions aren't powerful enough to parse XML properly.

Comment: I have an XML parser but it throws an error because of mismatched namespaces. So I have to parse the attributes and remove or fix invalid namespaces. PS I only need to work with the first tag to add the namespaces. I'm not doing any other string manipulations.

Comment: I think instead of using regex you'd better use replace `.replace(' =','=').replace('= ','=')` before splitting

Comment: That was it @AminJafari. Put that as an answer. Here is the Regex `\s+=\s+|=\s+|\s+=`

Comment: Try this regex: `split(/\s+(?!=|"|')/g)`

Comment: nah, it's not a good answer and doesn't worth posting, glad it helped though

Comment: @EvgeniyMaynagashev not sure how but that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex for your split, with negative lookahead:

`split(/\s+(?!=|"|')/g`

Result:

```
Array[4]
0:"something"
1:"xmlns:s = "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark""
2:"xmlns:b="testnamespace.com""
3:"xmlns="noprefix.com""
```

Comment: My friend is a beginner and he wants to know what is `(?!=|"|')` doing?

Comment: Checks for NOT having `=`, `"`, `'` after whitespace(s). If one of these symbols found, pattern doesn't match and function will not split in that place. It will be better if we can check for `=` before whitespace (lookbehind) and not use `"` and `'`, but as I know lookbehind not working in javascript regexp. 
Live demo: https://regex101.com/r/Y4BqLg/2